# How to download edit history from Google Docs

Tags: google-docs, google-takeout

I love Google Doc's edit history because I can see when I created files and then modified them later. **Is there anyway to download this edit history for a particular document?**

Ideally, I'd like to download all of the edit histories for all of my documents using Google Takeout, but Google Takeout only appears to download the most recent file and does not allow me to export the edit history of any of my files.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to do that except by downloading past revision files individually. Google Drive API has some mechanism for downloading all past revisions, but it can get quite involved: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-revisions?hl=en.

Comment: From the link to the API: “Revisions for Google Docs, Sheets, and Slides can’t be downloaded”

Comment: @ProQ So when Google says you can easily take all your data out, they are really lying, because unless you write your own software all your version history is stuck in the silo... :'-(

Comment: The link you have provided is to download past versions of Drive files *not* the edit history from a Google Doc.

Comment: @Michael, yes, that appears to be correct. You can't take your file edit history out of Drive. It does seem deceitful on their part.